# CONVERT decimal to hexadecimal in assembly language NASM

Tags: hex, decimal, nasm

This is one of the hexadecimal part from my code, and i a little bit stuck in the hexadecimal part. when i key in 2560(decimal) and the output is :00(hexadecimal). it give me right value , but i need A in instead of : . Anyone can tell me where is my problem. i will appreciated with your help.thanks.

DecToHex:

```
mov eax, msg8
call sprint

mov edx, 255
mov ecx, sinput8
mov ebx, 0
mov eax, 3
int 80h

mov eax, sinput8

call atoiToHex
call iprintLFToHex
ret
```

iprintToHex:

```
push    eax             
push    ecx             
push    edx           
push    esi             

mov     ecx, 0
```

divideLoopToHex:

```
inc     ecx              
mov     edx, 0         
mov     esi, 16      
idiv    esi            
add     edx, 48         
push    edx            
cmp     eax, 0          
jnz     divideLoopToHex
```

printLoopToHex:

```
dec     ecx             
mov     eax, esp        
call    sprint          
pop     eax             
cmp     ecx, 0          
jnz     printLoopToHex       

pop     esi            
pop     edx             
pop     ecx             
pop     eax             
ret
```

iprintLFToHex:

```
call    iprintToHex     
push    eax            
mov     eax, 0Ah         
mov     eax, esp        
call    sprint          
pop     eax            
pop     eax             
ret
```

atoiToHex:

```
push    ebx             
push    ecx             
push    edx             
push    esi             
mov     esi, eax        
mov     eax, 0          
mov     ecx, 0
```

.multiplyLoopToHex:

```
xor     ebx, ebx        
mov     bl, [esi+ecx]   
cmp     bl, 48          
jl      .finishedToHex  
cmp     bl, 70          
jg      .finishedToHex  
cmp     bl, 10          
je      .finishedToHex 
cmp     bl, 0           
jz      .finishedToHex  

sub     bl, 48         
add     eax, ebx        
mov     ebx, 10         
mul     ebx             
inc     ecx             
jmp     .multiplyLoop
```

.finishedToHex:

```
mov     ebx, 10         
div     ebx             
pop     esi            
pop     edx            
pop     ecx             
pop     ebx             
ret
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Decimal to Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533119/converting-decimal-to-hex)